# Can I upgrade to Windows 10 if I got a broken Windows 8 installation?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-8, windows-10, grub

I had 2 partitions, one was for Ubuntu Linux, (100 GB) and one was for Windows 8.1 (400 GB). I am dual-booting it with GRUB. Since I installed Ubuntu, it simply broke.

My question is: How can I install the Windows 10 update for free, since I got a broken Windows 8.1 installation? Can I install Windows 10 and enable it with my Windows 8 key?

Comment: If it is needed, I can edit my question and be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I install Windows 10 and enable it with my Windows 8 key?

This cannot be done at this time.  Once the Windows 10 Threshold 2 update is released on [November 10th](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_cortana/when-will-conrtana-available-in-india/b875cfba-6c2f-4f2d-82cd-0a56e98ed857?auth=1) 2015 it will be possible.  You will have to wait until the [Media Creation Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) is updated to to provide you the correct .ISO.  Doing the upgrade before this update is released will result in a installation that cannot be activated until that update is installed.

The current released .ISO will not accept your Windows 8.1 license key.  The installer contained within the current .ISO for the RTM build will not accept your Windows 8.1 license.  Windows 10 RTM also cannot be activated with a Windows 8.1 key.

> I saw an other answer saying that on 2nd of November 2015 I will be
>   able to enable Windows 10 with a Windows 8.1 License. Are you saying
>   that?

Microsoft explained in a blog post that as of Windows Insider Build 10565 Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 8.1 now can activate Windows 10.  They continued to indicate that the updated Windows 10 installation process would also accept Windows 7, Windows 8, and Windows 8.1 license keys.

This does not change the fact Windows 10 must be activated on your machine before July 29th 2016 in order for it to be free.

> How can I install the Windows 10 update for free, since I got a broken
>   Windows 8.1 installation?

Resolving the problem with your Windows 8.1 installation is the optimal solution.  Once you fix the installation you just download the update and perform the upgrade.

> If you install this build of the Windows 10 Insider Preview on a PC
>   and it doesn't automatically activate, you can enter the product key
>   from Windows 7, Windows 8 or Windows 8.1 used to activate the prior
>   Windows version on the same device to activate Windows 10 by going to
>   Settings > Update & security > Activation and selecting Change Product
>   Key.

[Announcing Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 10565](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/10/12/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-10565/)

Comment: I am kind of a noob with Windows, and it is kinda hard for me to understand the answer.
I saw an other answer saying that on 2nd of November 2015 I will be able to enable Windows 10 with a Windows 8.1 License.

Are you saying that?

Comment: @PanV - I say exactly that in my answer.  I don't understand your confusion.

Comment: Oopsie! My fault. I will confirm your asnwer.

Comment: @Ramhound If you contact Microsoft support and provide them with your old Windows 8.1 key they will generate you a Windows 10 key from it. I know because I did it.

Comment: @Insane - This goes against every single bit of information I have read on the subject.  I won't be including that footnote in my answer.

Comment: @ Ramhound That's fine but you can just call activation support, tell them Windows 10 won't activate and explain you had to clean install because your Windows 8.1 install broke. Eventually they'll transfer you and the next department will ask for proof of purchase and the old Windows key. Try it for your own sake if you want. @PanV I suggest you at least try.

Comment: I don't have a machine that won't activate.  I would have to lie in order to do what you suggest.  I also suspect it was a very regional thing, only read one other case, and that also was a regional situation.

Comment: I don't think I still got the proof, but I will look for it.
Or I will just wait 2 days

Comment: @Insane I will just do it, I just broke that USB port which my tablet charges from. Nothing else to do then!

Comment: Could you please update the answer, because Windows 10 Threshold Update 2 is out?

Comment: @PanV - Except it isn't?  I already updated it.  All I would do is remove the date infomation.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I install the Windows 10 update for free, since I got a broken Windows 8.1 installation?

Reinstall/repair Windows 8.1 so you have a working version, then upgrade.

> Can I install Windows 10 and enable it with my Windows 8 key?

Nope, at least not right now.

I've seen reports claim that in a recent Insider build (10565) that "[Windows 10 can now be activate[d] with Windows 7, 8 and 8.1 keys](http://changewindows.org/desktop.php)", but I've not actually tested that myself.

You can get the Insider build(s) directly from MS [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewiso).

If you don't want to/can't join the Insider program, you may have to wait until the Windows 10 "Fall Update"/"Threshold 2" is officially released via Microsoft.

Comment: The current Windows Insider build is [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewiso) and can be installed with a Windows 7, Windows 8, or Windows 8.1 license key (*at least in theory*).  Windows Insider after July 29th is only suppose to be activated for people who already had activated Windows 10 Insider Preview once on their machine ( before that date ) or had installed Windows 10 RTM and activated it.

Comment: @Ramhound, nice -- updated my answer.

Comment: Only looked it up because "I don't know" statements are a pet peeve of mine :-)

Comment: @Ramhound Then you must be peeved by most of the questions that get asked here. ;)

Comment: So.. if I install Insider Preview then enable it with a Windows 8.1 License I can upgrade to normal Windows 10?
I kinda like that method, but I guess I will just wait 3 days. :)

Comment: Yes; You can install the current build then update to the Threshold 2 build, opt out of Windows Insider, but that's a horrible upgrade path in my opinion

Comment: I will just wait 2 days

Answer (score 0):

From November 10th you can use your windows 8 key to perform a clean windows 10 installation. You can make the setup media from another pc using the tool that is located here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: Could you please be a bit more specific? I am a Windows n00b and I would like to know for example, why can I use windows 8 key after November 2nd.

Comment: @PanV Microsoft will release an update to Windows 10 on november 2nd, and one of these changes will allow windows 7 and 8 keys to be used to install Windows 10.